# Dispersing ultrasound in a tube - patters

Tags: experimental-physics, acoustics, dispersion

I am looking for patterns (Surface texture, inserted material, grooves, spirals, elasticity of materials etc) to efficiently disperse reflected ultrasound in the range of wavelengths 1mm to 4mm within the interior of a narrow tube (I do not want wall reflections). For various reasons absorption does not appear to be a solution. Thickness is also critical in that the surface must not be much more than 1mm deep. This is part of a setup for measuring absorption in gases using reflected pulses.

Comment: What do you mean by "disperse"?  Do you want the signal to be attenuated upon contact with the tube, and why?  Is there some reason you want only divergent sound waves attenuated and not those passing parallel to the tube axis?

Comment: I do not want reflections from the walls to add noise or alter the phase of the received signal (its pulsed).

Comment: Well, after setting an MSc student on it as a project for her MSc thesis we have an answer. In short, a woven pattern of glass fibre matting. Exact details of the engineering solution are confidential.

Comment: No problem, I'll have the NSA post the results.  BTW,  where does her school get off allowing restrictions on the publication of a thesis?

Comment: There are no restrictions. It is Imperial College London. I just don't want to link to it here, nor am I able to supply the final details of its implementation in a working instrument, which differs slightly from the work for the thesis.

Comment: There's no actual question here. The *implied* question is "what pattern disperses ultrasound in a tube"? Pattern of what? Can you be more specific about the definition of the system and ask a specific question?

Comment: Surface texture, inserted material, grooves, spirals, elasticity of materials... Just altered the question. However, as I said, we later made this an MSc project and let the student do the leg work. All experiment and almost no theory (apart from guessing at wavelength variations)